# nicEdit inside jquery accordion

Tags: php, jquery, html

when I put nicEditor outside accordion, it works fine. But when I put nicEditor inside accordion, the result is in the image. Can someone help me with this conflict?

[Outside jquery accordion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VihmF.png)

[inside jquery accordion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB6Er.png)

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#addQuestion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../user/nicedit/nicEdit.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>

<!-- TEXT AREA OF nicEditor OUTSIDE ACCORDION -->
<textarea name="area1" cols="40"></textarea><br>
<!-- END -->  


<!-- ADD QUESTION -->
    <div id="addQuestion">
    <div class="addQuestionHeader">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Question</div>
       <form action="" method="POST">
            <!-- TEXT AREA OF nicEditor INSIDE ACCORDION -->
<textarea name="area1" cols="40"></textarea><br>
<!-- END -->
            <input type="text" name="correctAnswer" placeholder="Correct Answer" class="form-control" autocomplete = "off"><br>
            <input type="text" name="optionOne" placeholder="Option One" class="form-control" autocomplete = "off"><br>
            <input type="text" name="optionTwo" placeholder="Option Two" class="form-control" autocomplete = "off"><br>
            <input type="text" name="optionThree" placeholder="Option Three" class="form-control" autocomplete = "off"><br>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnQuestionAdd" value="Save">
   <?php
      include('db/dbconfig.php');
   ?>
</form>
</div>
<!-- ADD QUESTION -->
```

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved in style only -.-

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6q7G.png)